# Java - Android SDK - savedInstanceState & onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save the state of the counters (mCreate, mRestart...etc) and load them once the onCreate() method is established. For some reason it always revert back to '0' whenever onCreate() is called.

```
// Use these as keys when you're saving state between reconfigurations
private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
private static final String START_KEY = "start";
private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Has previous state been saved?
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {           
        this.mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
        this.mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
        this.mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
        this.mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);
    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
savedInstanceState.containsKey(RESTART_KEY);
savedInstanceState.containsKey(RESUME_KEY);
savedInstanceState.containsKey(START_KEY);
savedInstanceState.containsKey(CREATE_KEY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call

```
savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, _your_key_);
```

in the "onSaveInstanceState" methode

Comment: This is exactly what I did to fix it. This link explained everything: The answer was explained in this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

I checked [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). I couldn't find any function "containsKEY" in the Bundle Class. However I think you should use

```
    savedInstanceState.putString("restartkey",RESTART_KEY);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("resumekey",RESUME_KEY);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("startkey",START_KEY);
    savedInstanceState.addString("createkey",CREATE_KEY);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to flexibly use this command. I got it fixed.